# php json array getting duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

im trying to get the total daily, hourly as the hourly total being set to sub array from total daily which the starting date will create duplicate array on the next date so on..

php script:

```
   $sql = "SELECT cs_id, dated, count(p_id) as day_total FROM post_logs
 where cs_id = '$cs_id' and dated BETWEEN '2021-06-01' and '2021-06-30'
 group by dated order by dated";
 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);  
    while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($result))  { 
    $dated = $row['dated'];      
    $cs_id = $row['cs_id'];     
    $dt = $row['day_total'];
      
    $sql2 = "SELECT dated, date_format(actual,'%H:00') as hours, count(p_id) as hour_total 
    FROM post_logs where cs_id = '$cs_id' and dated = '$dated' group by date_format(actual,'%H') >order by dated"; 

    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);  
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
      
       $data2[] = $row2;
    } //r2
      
    $data[] = array('date_id' => sha1($dated), 'name' => $dated, 'day_total' => $dt, 'data2' => $data2);    
 } //r1
  echo json_encode($data);
```

the json output:

```
[{"date_id":"cb603e7403310cd0130e451aa095501689164b23","name":"2021-06-21","day_total":"12","data2":[{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"15:00","hour_total":"2"},{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"16:00","hour_total":"1"},{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"17:00","hour_total":"2"},{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"18:00","hour_total":"2"},{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"19:00","hour_total":"1"},{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"20:00","hour_total":"3"},{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"23:00","hour_total":"1"}]},{"date_id":"54ec9a5871943347c9c6a750b0b11e93744616c1","name":"2021-06-22","day_total":"10","data2":[{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"15:00","hour_total":"2"},{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"16:00","hour_total":"1"},{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"17:00","hour_total":"2"},{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"18:00","hour_total":"2"},{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"19:00","hour_total":"1"},{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"20:00","hour_total":"3"},{"dated":"2021-06-21","hours":"23:00","hour_total":"1"},{"dated":"2021-06-22","hours":"02:00","hour_total":"1"},{"dated":"2021-06-22","hours":"05:00","hour_total":"1"},{"dated":"2021-06-22","hours":"06:00","hour_total":"1"},{"dated":"2021-06-22","hours":"07:00","hour_total":"1"},{"dated":"2021-06-22","hours":"08:00","hour_total":"1"},{"dated":"2021-06-22","hours":"09:00","hour_total":"1"},{"dated":"2021-06-22","hours":"10:00","hour_total":"2"},{"dated":"2021-06-22","hours":"15:00","hour_total":"2"}]}]
```

As you can see, the date 06-21 has been repeated/duplicated onto the next/succeeding array where desired output is getting rid out of the duplicating issues..

regards,

Comment: Which MySQL version? You should be using `json_arrayagg` rather than having queries in loops. With this it should be possible to write a single query.

Comment: im sorry but im just noob but i tried that however "count(p_id) as day_total" stops the loops on hourly..

Comment: If data processing *may* be performed by DBMS it ***must*** be performed by DBMS. You must create **one** query which will build and return JSON which you need. Provide: CREATE TABLE of the table, INSERT INTO with some sample data (5-10 rows) and desired final output (JSON) with detailed explanations. And specify precise MySQL version.